# What url should i give on tag to save to CameraRoll react-native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-camera

While saving image to camera roll what uri should be given to the the 'tag' to save to camera roll.

I tried to give the path of camera roll as `asset-library://asset/`

but throws an error saying `Could not find asset with UUID (null)`

Answer (score 0):

It's actually expecting the uri of an image asset. So the method seems to only be able to update existing assets. Try deploying your app with a placeholder image and then have the app update it. Remember to pass in the placeholder image's uri.

Comment: But how will I put the placeholder image in the cameraroll? If I put the image in any other place, I don't suppose it will be a valid tag for `saveImageWithTag()` @harry-moreno